# How to persist a polymorphic collection with API Platform

Tags: symfony, polymorphism, api-platform.com

I'm developping a quotation tool with NextJS and an API developed with Symfony and API Platform.

A Quotation has a collection of QuotationRow which is extended by three others entities : QuotationRowProduct, QuotationRowText, QuotationRowSubtotal.

Below, the entire entities:

**Quotation.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Quotation;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Quotation\QuotationRow;
use App\Repository\QuotationRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\DateFilter;
use App\Entity\Client;
use App\Entity\ClientAgency;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: QuotationRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: [
        "groups" => ["Quotation:get"]
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        "groups" => ["Quotation:post"]
    ]
)]
#[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['createdAt' => DateFilter::EXCLUDE_NULL])]
#[HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class Quotation
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column()]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get"])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private ?string $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private ?int $validityPeriod = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private ?string $comment = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'quotation', targetEntity: QuotationRow::class, orphanRemoval: true, cascade: ["all"])]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    #[ORM\OrderBy(["position" => "ASC"])]
    private $quotationRows;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le client est requis")]
    private ?Client $client = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private ?ClientAgency $clientAgency = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get"])]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get"])]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->quotationRows = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidityPeriod(): ?int
    {
        return $this->validityPeriod;
    }

    public function setValidityPeriod(int $validityPeriod): self
    {
        $this->validityPeriod = $validityPeriod;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setComment(?string $comment): self
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient(): ?Client
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setClient(?Client $client): self
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, QuotationRow>
     */
    public function getQuotationRows(): Collection
    {
        return $this->quotationRows;
    }

    public function addQuotationRow(QuotationRow $quotationRow): self
    {
        if (!$this->quotationRows->contains($quotationRow)) {
            $this->quotationRows[] = $quotationRow;
            $quotationRow->setQuotation($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeQuotationRow(QuotationRow $quotationRow): self
    {
        if ($this->quotationRows->removeElement($quotationRow)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($quotationRow->getQuotation() === $this) {
                $quotationRow->setQuotation(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClientAgency(): ?ClientAgency
    {
        return $this->clientAgency;
    }

    public function setClientAgency(?ClientAgency $clientAgency): self
    {
        $this->clientAgency = $clientAgency;

        return $this;
    }

    #[ORM\PrePersist]
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $currDateTime = new DateTime();
        $this->createdAt = $currDateTime;
        $this->updatedAt = $currDateTime;
        $this->status = "waiting";
    }

    #[ORM\PreUpdate]
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

**QuotationRow.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Quotation;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Quotation\Quotation;
use App\Entity\Quotation\QuotationRowText;
use App\Repository\QuotationRowRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Entity\Quotation\QuotationRowProduct;
use App\Entity\Quotation\QuotationRowSubtotal;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: QuotationRowRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: "type", type: "string")]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    "product" => QuotationRowProduct::class,
    "subtotal" => QuotationRowSubtotal::class,
    "text" => QuotationRowText::class,
])]
class QuotationRow
{

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get"])]
    protected int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Quotation::class, inversedBy: 'quotationRows')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    protected ?Quotation $quotation;

    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    #[ORM\Column]
    protected ?int $position;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getQuotation(): ?Quotation
    {
        return $this->quotation;
    }

    public function setQuotation(?Quotation $quotation): self
    {
        $this->quotation = $quotation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition(): int
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(int $position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }

    public function setType($type = "unknown"): self
    {
        $this->type = "unknown";
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**QuotationRowProduct.php**

```
<?php


namespace App\Entity\Quotation;

use App\Entity\VAT;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\QuotationRowRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: QuotationRowRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class QuotationRowProduct extends QuotationRow
{

    const TYPE = "product";


    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private float $preTaxPrice;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private int $quantity;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private string $description;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private float $preTaxDiscount;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private float $discountRate;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: VAT::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private ?VAT $vat;

    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return self::TYPE;
    }

    public function getPreTaxPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->preTaxPrice;
    }

    public function setPreTaxPrice(float $preTaxPrice): self
    {
        $this->preTaxPrice = $preTaxPrice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): self
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPreTaxDiscount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->preTaxDiscount;
    }

    public function setPreTaxDiscount(float $preTaxDiscount): self
    {
        $this->preTaxDiscount = $preTaxDiscount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDiscountRate(): ?float
    {
        return $this->discountRate;
    }

    public function setDiscountRate(float $discountRate): self
    {
        $this->discountRate = $discountRate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVat(): ?VAT
    {
        return $this->vat;
    }

    public function setVat(?VAT $vat): self
    {
        $this->vat = $vat;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setType($type = "product"): self
    {
        $this->type = "product";
        return $this;
    }


    // Utility

    public function getSubtotalWithoutVAT()
    {
        $price = $this->preTaxPrice * $this->quantity;
        return $price - ($price * $this->discountRate / 100);
    }

    public function getSubtotalWithVAT()
    {
        $price = $this->getSubtotalWithoutVAT();
        return $price + ($price * $this->vat->getRate() / 100);
    }
}
```

**QuotationRowSubtotal.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Quotation;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Quotation\QuotationRow;
use App\Repository\QuotationRowRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: QuotationRowRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class QuotationRowSubtotal extends QuotationRow
{

    const TYPE = "subtotal";

    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return self::TYPE;
    }

    private function getAllRows()
    {
        return $this->quotation->getQuotationRows();
    }

    /**
     * Return all subtotals in the Quotation#rows list
     * @return QuotationRowSubtotal[]
     */
    private function getSubtotalRows()
    {
        $filtered = [];

        foreach ($this->getAllRows() as $row) {
            if ($row instanceof QuotationRowSubtotal) {
                $filtered[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $filtered;
    }

    /**
     * Get the previous Subtotal priority
     * @return integer
     */
    private function getPrevSubtotalPos()
    {

        // Reverse result for find more quicker the last subtotal
        $subtotalRows = array_reverse($this->getSubtotalRows());

        foreach ($subtotalRows as $row) {
            if ($this->position > $row->getPosition()) {
                return $row->getPosition();
            }
        }

        // Return -1 if any result for the next function condition
        return -1;
    }



    /**
     * Return the Subtotal from the last Subtotal without VAT
     * @return float
     */
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get"])]
    public function getSubtotal()
    {
        $lastPosition = $this->getPrevSubtotalPos();
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($this->getAllRows() as $row) {
            if ($row->getPosition() < $this->position && $row->getPosition() > $lastPosition) {
                if ($row instanceof QuotationRowProduct) {
                    $total += $row->getSubtotalWithoutVAT();
                }
            }
        }
        return $total;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Subtotal from the last Subtotal with VAT
     * @return float
     */
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get"])]
    public function getSubtotalWithVat()
    {
        $lastPosition = $this->getPrevSubtotalPos();
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($this->getAllRows() as $row) {
            if ($row->getPosition() < $this->position && $row->getPosition() > $lastPosition) {
                if ($row instanceof QuotationRowProduct) {
                    $total += $row->getSubtotalWithVAT();
                }
            }
        }
        return $total;
    }
}
```

**QuotationRowText.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Quotation;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Quotation\QuotationRow;
use App\Repository\QuotationRowRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: QuotationRowRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class QuotationRowText extends QuotationRow
{
    const TYPE = "text";

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    private string $text;

    #[Groups(["Quotation:get", "Quotation:post"])]
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return self::TYPE;
    }

    public function getText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setText(string $text): self
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see above in **Quotation.php**, the collection of QuotationRow is persisted by the Quotation entity.

The probleme is when I do a POST request to the API  on /api/quotations endpoint, the API throw an SQL error : "column 'type' cannot be null", but 'type' is the discriminator column.

So I tried somethings before write this topic:

1. Send 'type' in the body request to the API: it's ignored by the API
2. Map $type as a protected property of QuotationRow : Makes an error because column 'type' already exsists in table 'quotation_row'.

I would like persist all QuotationRow from the Quotation API endpoint . Is there a way to persist a polymorphic collection in OneToMany context from the owner side ? Maybe by wrting a custom API Controller ?

Note that: there is no problem to update QuotationRow when they already exist in database, only to persist them.